# Stash Notifier - Post build comment

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, bcbsn

I have a jenkins upstream DSL job A.

It has a Stash Notifier which notifies back to Bitbucket (including post build comments).

Once this job A is success, it notifies the stash (either success or failure) and on success ,it then triggers a parameterized downstream DSL job B.

And here I am trying to to notify the status of job B (including post build comments) to the same Pull Request (PR) in Bitbucket.

But I don't get any post build comments back to the PR from job B.
Both jobs refers/checkout the same PR but tasks differ.

I am able to see post build comments from job A but nothing from job B.

I have also added all the required parameters from upstream to downstream job